# Get length of text in *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

I am fairly new to Angular (8) and I try to get the length of the input value, which I created in a `*ngFor` like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let panel of panels; index as i" class="panel" [id]="'panel-' + panel.id">
    <div>{{ panel.title }}</div>
    <input matInput placeholder="Bezeichnung" [(ngModel)]="panel.title" />
</div>
```

How would I access the length of the `panel.title` in my class?

This is my interface/class

```
export interface ProgressbarStepData {
    // Each progressbar step is represented by an instance of this data type.
    id: number; // Unique ID
    title: string; // The label that is displayed as the step title.
    color: string; // Hex code of the colored markings associated with this step. Only visible in Builder, not Viewer.
    order: number; // Denotes which step this is (from step 1 to <number of steps>)
}

export class ProgressbarEditorComponent implements OnInit {
    public panels: Array<ProgressbarStepData> = []; // One panel for each existing progressbar step

   ...
```

What would I need to get the length of the input currently typing in?

**EDIT**

To clarify what I want to achieve: I want to count the characters typed in the CURRENT input and trigger an alert from the class (not from the template itself)

Comment: Show input currently that the user typing in

Comment: Can you please clarify a little bit what do you mean by getting the length? What is exactly the use case you are trying to solve? If you could provide a bit more detail it would help in providing an answer

Comment: I want to count the characters typed in by the user

Comment: Where are you typing?? Where you want to get result?\

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I removed the `<input>` by accident while reducing the sample. It's back in now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ngModel` needs to be bound to `panels` not to `panel` in the `ngFor`. You can do this using the `index`.

```html
<div *ngFor="let panel of panels; index as i" class="panel" [id]="'panel-' + panel.id">
    <div>{{ panel.title }}</div>
    <input matInput placeholder="Bezeichnung" [(ngModel)]="panels[i].title" (blur)="showAlert(i)" />
</div>
```

Then trigger the alert in the component by passing in the index and use that to get the length of the panel title. I have used the `blur` event here.

```js
showAlert(index) {
    const titleLength = this.panels[index].title.length;
    // Call alert with the length of the title here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
<div *ngFor="let panel of panels; index as i" class="panel" [id]="'panel-' + panel.id">
    <div>{{ panel.title }}</div>
    <input (change)="onChange({{panel.title}})" matInput placeholder="Bezeichnung" [(ngModel)]="panel.title" />
</div>


onChange(title) {
          console.log(title.length);
         })
```

Comment: While this works, I would like to have it only count the characters of the current input typed in and I don't understand how I would access that in the class?

Comment: It did indeed, thank you very much. I changed `(change)` to `(ngModelChange)` (not sure if that is actually better), so yes, thanks! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

## .html

```
<input type="text" (input)="inputMthd($event)"  (keyup)="methodCalled($event)">
```

## .ts

```
inputMthd(e){
console.log(e);
event.target.value.length;
}
methodCalled(e){
console.log(e);
e.target.value.length;
}
```

Comment: Try to be more descriptive in your explanation.
In addition to adding the code as response, try to add a brief explanation of why comes in handy.